# Using and injecting from appsettings.json in unit tests on .net core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, mstest, appsettings

I have created an asp.net core web application and a unit test application.

I created the asp.net application using the "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)" template and created the unit test project using the "Class Library (.NET Core)" template.

I configured MSTest using the instructions on the following article:

[Announcing MSTest Framework support for .NET Core RC2 / ASP.NET Core RC2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/30/announcing-mstest-framework-support-for-net-core-rc2-asp-net-core-rc2/)

I have organised the application into Controllers and Services, the controllers read values from appsettings.json and pass these into the service methods as arguments.

I have an AppSettings class as follows

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string Setting1 { get; set; }
    public string Setting2 { get; set; }
    public string Setting3etc { get; set; }
}

public static class App
{
    public static AppSettings Settings { get; set; }

    public static void ConfigureSettings(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
    {
        Settings = settings.Value; 
    }
}
```

The controller constructor is as follows

```
public ValuesController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
{            
    App.ConfigureSettings(settings);
}
```

In Startup.cs I have the following line in the `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

I learned about this technique from the following article

[Strongly Typed Configuration Settings in ASP.NET Core](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/may/23/strongly-typed-configuration-settings-in-aspnet-core)

This works at run time, but I'm having difficulties accessing these settings in my unit tests.

I'm trying to find a way to get the values from appsettings.json into my test project, so that I can pass them to the controllers and services.

My test methods look something like this

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Service - Method1")]
public void ServiceMethod1Test()
{
    // this compiles but gets null reference exception
    var setting1 = App.Settings.Setting1;
    var setting2 = App.Settings.Setting2;

    var service = new Service(setting1, setting2);

    var argument1 = "argument";
    var actual = service.Method1(argument1);
    var expected = "expected result";

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Controller - Method1")]
public void ControllerMethod1Test()
{
    // how do i create this settings instance?
    var settings = ???

    var controler = new ValuesController(settings);

    var argument1 = "argument";

    var actual = controller.Method1(argument1);
    var expected = "expected result";

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

How could I go about passing an instance of a class that implements 
`IOptions<MySettings>` to the controller constructor for controller tests, and how could I go about getting those values to pass to service methods in the service tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integration test with IOptions<> in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649045/integration-test-with-ioptions-in-net-core)

Answer (score 8):

Just reference the Options package and use

```
IOptions<MyOptions> options = Options.Create(new MyOptions()
{
    ...
});
```

See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/Options.cs#L14-L17) for source code reference.