# Resolve IStringLocalizer with real resx manually

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am looking for a way to resolve `IStringLocalizer<T>` objects with the real underlying resx files, using a similar method to how I resolved `IOptions` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019988/servicecollection-returns-null-for-ioptions-even-though-getsection-is-working).

This is in order to build unit tests that will chek each resx for each language to ensure the strings are implemented.

If it can't be done using the standard resolving of a `IStringLocalizer<MyStringClass>` type, then any other ways I can easily access the key value pairs from the resx would be helpful.

I've done some searching but not having much luck. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the source repo to see how they do it for their unit tests? It should be able to give you some examples of how to adapt it to your use case.

Comment: The documentation should also be of some help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization

Comment: According to docs `AddLocalization Adds the localization services to the services container.`

Answer (score 19):

You can directly instantiate a **StringLocalizer** instance, passing in a **ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory** to its constructor.

The **ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory** will take care of retrieving the actual localization values from the resource file.

So for example:

```
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

    ...

public void MyTest() 
{
    var options = Options.Create(new LocalizationOptions());  // you should not need any params here if using a StringLocalizer<T>
    var factory = new ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory(options, NullLoggerFactory.Instance);
    var localizer = new StringLocalizer<MyResourceFile>(factory);

    var myText = localizer["myText"];  // text using default culture

    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr");
    var myFrenchText = localizer["myText"];  // text in French

}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, but for me, it worked with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr"); to change the culture.

Comment: Thanks.  This was the only example I could find.  Microsoft's "documentation" had ZERO examples.