# How can I build an IOptionsMonitor<T> for testing?

Tags: dependency-injection, configuration, .net-core, appsettings

For the normal IOptions interface, you can manually build an instance e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262906/how-to-build-ioptionst-for-testing).

Is there any equivalent way to make an IOptionsMonitor instance without using DI?

Answer (score 21):

You can do something like below and and then use that for testing:

```
    public class TestOptionsMonitor : IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions>
    {
        public TestOptionsMonitor(MyOptions currentValue)
        {
            CurrentValue = currentValue;
        }

        public MyOptions Get(string name)
        {
            return CurrentValue;
        }

        public IDisposable OnChange(Action<MyOptions, string> listener)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public MyOptions CurrentValue { get; }
    }
```

Comment: Very cool, can a generic class be made which can create OptionsMonitor for any kind of type? That would be very useful. EDIT; already made, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57090899/6352803

Answer (score 21):

nice answer from Hananiel

Here the generic version of it:

```
public class TestOptionsMonitor<T> : IOptionsMonitor<T>
    where T : class, new()
{
    public TestOptionsMonitor(T currentValue)
    {
        CurrentValue = currentValue;
    }

    public T Get(string name)
    {
        return CurrentValue;
    }

    public IDisposable OnChange(Action<T, string> listener)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T CurrentValue { get; }
}
```

and simply create an instance with your object!

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: If you're avoiding external libraries the previous answers will do the trick! Consider this one if you'd like to leverage an existing library to Mock stuff for you!*

If you're using the `NSubstitute` library for Mocking you can mock out an `IOptionsMonitor` by doing the following:

```cs
// Arrange
var mockedOptions = Substitute.For<IOptionsMonitor<BasicCredentialSchemaOptions>>();
mockedOptions.CurrentValue.Returns(new BasicCredentialSchemaOptions(/*snip*/));

// Act
var result = mockOptions.CurrentValue;    // Does not throw and fires off NSubstitue's Returns

// Assert
Assert.NotNull(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because iOptionsMonitor is not the subject of your test, **you can replace it by a mock that simulate the behaviour of the real object**.

Using [moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4):

```cs
var iOptionsMonitor =
     Mock
     .Of<IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions>>(
        x => 
           x.CurrentValue.YourOption1 == "some value" &&
           x.CurrentValue.YourOption2 == 21 &&
           x.CurrentValue.YourOption3 == true
     );
```

Remember to [install Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/) package:

```sh
dotnet add package Moq
```

Be free to setup your mock for your custom needs. For example, to set behaviour for other interface methods (Get, OnChange)

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late, but here is a full implementation of a test options monitor you can use.

```cs
public class OptionsMonitorTestImplementation<TOptions> : IOptionsMonitor<TOptions>
{
    public OptionsMonitorTestImplementation(TOptions initialValue) => CurrentValue = initialValue;

    readonly List<Action<TOptions, string>> _listeners = new();
    public TOptions CurrentValue { get; private set; }
    public TOptions Get(string name) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IDisposable OnChange(Action<TOptions, string> listener)
    {
        _listeners.Add(listener);
        return new ActionDisposable(() => _listeners.Remove(listener));
    }

    public void UpdateOptions(TOptions options)
    {
        CurrentValue = options;
        _listeners.ForEach(listener => listener(options, string.Empty));
    }
    
    public sealed class ActionDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        readonly Action _action;

        public ActionDisposable(Action action) => _action = action;

        public void Dispose() => _action();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the samples above worked for me because the code calls OnChange and it throws `NotImplementedException`.

Here is the code I ended up using.

```
public class TestOptionsMonitor<TOptions> : IOptionsMonitor<TOptions>
{
    private Action<TOptions, string>? _listener;

    public TestOptionsMonitor(TOptions currentValue) => CurrentValue = currentValue;

    public TOptions CurrentValue { get; private set; }

    public TOptions Get(string name) => CurrentValue;

    public void Set(TOptions value)
    {
        CurrentValue = value;
        _listener?.Invoke(value, string.Empty);
    }

    public IDisposable OnChange(Action<TOptions, string> listener)
    {
        _listener = listener;
        return Mock.Of<IDisposable>();
    }
}
```

Which is based on this blog.
https://benfoster.io/blog/20200610-testing-ioptionsmonitor/

Answer (score -2):

I was going crazy trying to mock the object, this was much easier. Just new up a TestOptionsMonitor

```
var options = new TestOptionsMonitor(new MyOptions{ Option1 = "Test" });
```

using the above TestOptionsMonitor and you'll be good to go